# How to read a generic XML file in java

Tags: java, xml

I'm looking for ways to read a generic xml file

Here is an example of a normal xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<students>
    <student>
        <name>John</name>
        <grade>B</grade>
        <age>12</age>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Mary</name>
        <grade>A</grade>
        <age>11</age>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Simon</name>
        <grade>A</grade>
        <age>18</age>
    </student>
</students>
```

and here is example of a typical xml parser that would read that code and print it out

```
public class XMLParser {

    public void getAllUserNames(String fileName) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            File file = new File(fileName);
            if (file.exists()) {
                Document doc = db.parse(file);
                Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement();

                // Print root element of the document
                System.out.println("Root element of the document: "
                        + docEle.getNodeName());

                NodeList studentList = docEle.getElementsByTagName("student");

                // Print total student elements in document
                System.out
                        .println("Total students: " + studentList.getLength());

                if (studentList != null && studentList.getLength() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.getLength(); i++) {

                        Node node = studentList.item(i);

                        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                            System.out
                                    .println("=====================");

                            Element e = (Element) node;
                            NodeList nodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("name");
                            System.out.println("Name: "
                                    + nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0)
                                            .getNodeValue());

                            nodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("grade");
                            System.out.println("Grade: "
                                    + nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0)
                                            .getNodeValue());

                            nodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("age");
                            System.out.println("Age: "
                                    + nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0)
                                            .getNodeValue());
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        parser.getAllUserNames("c:\\test.xml");
    }
}
```

This code needs lines like this

```
NodeList studentList = docEle.getElementsByTagName("student");

NodeList nodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("name");
```

In order to work correctly.

My questions comes from how would I make that generic. Is there any way where I could read that same XML file without having to get specific elements by tagNames and yet still print it out in a view able format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a generic function to handle.

Generic function is as follows:

```
/* Prints the Node Value */
public void PrintNodeValue(Element element, String tagName, String msg)
{
    NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    System.out.println(msg + nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
}
```

Function is called as below:

```
PrintNodeValue(e, "name", "Name: ");
PrintNodeValue(e, "grade", "Grade: ");
```

Answer (score -1):

In the above example you are using Dom parser. By using Jaxb Context unmarshaller you can convert the xml to java object,  then you can achive your task.